# need to display list of student according to the option selected in dropdown

Tags: angular

I have a list of students and their opted courses.Now there is an dropdown menu in which list of courses is shown and by selecting a course from dropdown menu, list of student who have opted that particular course should be displayed.
IN .ts

```
allStudents : Student[]=[
{name:'James',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Kary',course:'Android'},
{name:'Bob',course:'Java'},
{name:'Pam',course:'Java'},
{name:'Steve',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Williams',course:'Android'},
{name:'Julis',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Matt',course:'Java'},
{name:'Willy',course:'Android'},
];
```

And in HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="crse" (keyup)="show()">
    <option value=''>Courses...</option>
    <option value="ang">Angular</option>
    <option value="and">Android</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    </select>
    </div>
 <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light">Name</div>
<div class="col-4 bg-dark text-light">Course</div>
<div class="row" *ngFor="let st of showStudents">
 <div class="col-4 border">{{st.name}}</div>
 <div class="col-4 border">{{st.course}}</div>
 </div></div></div>
```

Need to do this using Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed `keyup` to `(ngModelChange)="show(crse)"`

**HTML:**

```
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="crse" (ngModelChange)="show(crse)">
    <option value=''>Courses...</option>
    <option value="ang">Angular</option>
    <option value="and">Android</option>
    <option value="java">Java</option>
    </select>
```

And in **TS:** written new function `show(crse)` with **filter**,

```
show(crse) {
  let char = crse.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + crse.substr(1);
  let tempArray = [];
  this.allStudents.filter(function(x) {
    if(x.course.startsWith(char) === true) {
      tempArray.push(x);
    }
  });
  this.showStudents = tempArray;
}
```

**Working Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rknqw4

Comment: it is working:) but i want to do it without using function or ngModelchange..like just wanna use filter and the basic terms..as i am new in this and only these topics are only covered till now

Comment: instead of ngModelChange i used change and its working fine..similarly i just wanna use the basic terms of filter and angular to do this task..

Comment: @AmanSolanki, Both ```change``` and ```ngModelChange ``` will work... But i don't understand your actual requirement..

Comment: is there any other way of doing this same task..without using function in "this.allStudents.filter(function(x) " beacuse i havent covered that topic yet

Comment: its ok if you are not able to get me..:) this is will be fine. but what if i add a extra option in dropdown with name ALL and after selecting it..whole list of students should appear..how this will be done??

Comment: @AmanSolanki, I have updated the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rknqw4 with extra option called ```All``` please check it.. I hope this is what you want..

Comment: this did worked thanks:)  but need to know about one more edition what if i add check box near each option instead of dropdown..and can select multiple option from it..and show the list acc to the sleected checked box.@ManirajfromKarur

Comment: @AmanSolanki, Don't extend your requirement with adding and adding some additional features.. Try to elaborate what you need in single question.. Anyhow i was able to make it with checkbox in link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugfrpx but you need to uncheck the checked checkbox if you want select other option to see the result.. Thats all i can help you, hereafter i will not touch it for any requirement.. If you want anything customise yourself.. Happy Coding..

Comment: thanks @ManirajfromKarur sir i am new in this coding world so thats why just trying to extend my limits..thanks for your contribution..highlu appreciate this:)

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr=[
{name:'James',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Kary',course:'Android'},
{name:'Bob',course:'Java'},
{name:'Pam',course:'Java'},
{name:'Steve',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Williams',course:'Android'},
{name:'Julis',course:'Angular'},
{name:'Matt',course:'Java'},
{name:'Willy',course:'Android'},
];

var course="Angular";
let newar = arr.filter(res => res.course === course);
  console.log(newar)
```

```
if(this.crse === 'ang'){
this.crse='Angular';
}else if(this.crse === 'and'){
this.crse='Android';
}
else if(this.crse === 'java'){
this.crse='Java';
}
this.showStudents= this.allStudents.filter(res => res.course === this.crse);
```

It is better to assign option value as a complete course name to reduce the course name checking in the initial.

Comment: i am still confused..how to do this using a dropdown menu??